# Get name of abstract parent model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have a set of Django models that are all subclasses of an abstract Base model:

```
from django.db import models

class Base(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Derived1(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, unique=True)
    whatever = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I can get the Field objects for Derived1 like this:

```
fields=models.Derived1._meta.get_fields()
```

This gives me all the fields, including the inherited "created" field.
Once I have this list of fields, is there any way to see that the field "created" was inherited from Base? Does the field object have any function or property that tells me the name of the model on which "created" was defined? Specifically I'm looking for some function field.get_model_name_where_defined() so that for fields defined on Derived1, that function returns "Derived1" but for the "created" field it returns "Base". Does anything like this exist?

Just to be clear, I am not looking for a way to assert that Derived1 is derived from Base. What I am looking for is a way to check any Django model and get the unknown name of the model class that is its abstract superclass, if there is such a class.

Comment: Would `Derived1.__bases__`, `Derived1.__mro__`, or `import inspect; inspect.getmro(Derived1)` work?